# How to set base url class using flutter http package?

Tags: flutter, http

I am using HTTP package for API calls. I am not using the base URL class now, so I need to change the base URL everywhere once changing the base URL.  How do I create a class for keeping the base URL of API and use this class for getting the base URL during API calls?

**I am using HTTP package**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create separate class for apis like this

```
class Apis {
  static const _baseUrl = 'your_base_url';

  static const signUpApi = _baseUrl + 'singup_api_endpoint';
  static const loginApi = _baseUrl + 'login_api_endpoint';
}
```

And use as mentioned below

```
await http.get(Uri.parse(Apis.loginApi));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a constant file and then import the base_url from there. Or else, you can also make a class of constants and set its private constructor(so no one can make objects) and then set base_url to static to use directly without the class object.

```
class ApiConstants {`enter code here`
  ApiConstants._(); // private constructor

  static const BASE_URL = "your_url";
  static const API_KEY = "your_api_key";
}
```

To use this in another file,
step 1: import it.
step 2: Use ApiConstants.BASE_URL like below,

```
_client.get(
      Uri.parse('${ApiConstants.BASE_URL}$path'),
```

Upvote it, if it solves your problem.